# Mathematical tools of evaluating the efficiency of a vaccination dose

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have two groups of a vaccinated people. Group A receives only two doses while the second group receives three doses. Over time, people move from Group A to group B by receiving a second dosage. Each day, we have data on the number of critical condition patients, and how many people are within each group (the data is day-wise deterministic).

If the groups were constant, we could have calculated the statistical significance of the critical patients, and determine the benefits of the third dosage.

Assuming a causal link, between the third dose vaccination and the number of critical patients, how do I determine in the case of group transitions, if the third dose is efficient? Are there other tools other than statistical significance? Is there another way to apply statistical significance? How do they validate such data in scientific researches?

Also, the percentages of critical patients are very small for both groups. Does this change the way we calculate?

This question regards real data on COVID-19 vaccination. As you know, there is no decisive constant $n$  incubation period. The rate of people transitioning between groups is random and uncontrolled.

To sum up, what mathematical tools are available for the assertion that the third dose decreases the number of critical patients, assuming a causal link between the two?

Comment: What determines when people receive a second dose?

Comment: Is there a known *incubation period* of the virus so that if you have a single vaccination on day$:0$, and you then become ill on day$:n$, it can be determined whether you were infected before or after the day$:0$ vaccination?

Comment: Can't vote to close because bounty, but this is both far outside of mathematics, and far too broad.

Comment: @DanielV It is a question on applied statistical methods. Why is it put of scope?

Comment: @havakok It requires all kinds of value judgements to be made.  "is efficient" "benefits of" for example.  And the question requires the user to make probabilistic assumptions, which is not within the scope of mathematics.  Could you rephrase this question in terms of something like mixing paint or choosing marbles?  I think not.

Comment: @DanielV I strongly disagree with you. It is a hard question, yes. though it is a question in statistics, which as far as I knew is a branch of mathematics. I am not strong in this section of mathematics, hence the question, though I am sure that medical researchers are performing tests like this on their experiments. Vaccinations and drugs are tested statistically and not all statistics are choosing marbels. It is ok if you don't have the knowledge to supply an answer but you criticism on the subject is not supported.

Answer (score -2):

As has been mentioned in the comments, this is not quite a mathematical question, and the question lacks specificity. However, without writing off your query with no comment, I would like to point out one major consideration to hopefully help you understand the question you might be trying to ask:

What is statistical significance?

If you are familiar with statistical significance, then you might realize that determining whether or not the results of a study have "statistical significance" is dependent on the researcher's on choice. In case this is in unfamiliar territory, the first thing we would want to formulate is a set of hypotheses.

What is your null hypothesis, and what is your alternative hypothesis? What is the parameter you are measuring? What distribution are we using? These are all questions that should be answered before being able to talk about statistical significance.

Broadly speaking, statistical significance is tied to the likelihood of an experiment result to have been due to random chance, but requires a proper formulation of the problem you are studying in order to properly assess the related probabilities.

In short, the question you are asking seems to not be a question over statistical significance, but one that is more along the lines of a query regarding Experimental Design. This falls outside of the scope of Mathematics.

Comment: I did not ask how to apply statistical significance in this case. I asked how do I determine if the third does is efficient, that is, what are the mathematical tools to do so if any.

Comment: I have edited to clarify.

Comment: By the way, mathematical tools for experimental evaluation are a scope of mathematics.

Comment: Mathematical tools for evaluation are indeed in the scope of Mathematics, but in the way you have described the problem at hand, you are asking more about the design and how to make things "efficient" without providing mathematical context for the tools you are using (of which there are many, each of which depending on the design).

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I don't understand why you think that. Do you have any suggestions on to how to edit my question in order to clarify? I think it is clear enough as it is, and you simply need to read it again.

Comment: Noting the comments to the original post, I am not the first to note the many issues with your question, with regards to both the lack of mathematical clarity and its scope. You have not made it clear what it is you are asking from a mathematical perspective, but it seems that your understanding of statistical significance as a concept is tenuous.

Comment: If you are seeking a proper response to this question, you will need to provide a more concrete design including the types of data you are gathering, along with the distribution (be it parametric or non-parametric) you wish to use to analyze the results, as statistical significance cannot be discussed without that. Regardless of how clear you think your question may be, the issue is not one of lack of reading, but simply that your question is not well-defined, or mathematical in scope

Comment: I have supplied a description of the data, as detailed as I can think of. If something is missing, kindly request the specific details. Otherwise, I do not understand why you state that the "need to provide a more concrete design including the types of data you are gathering, along with the distribution". The data is, as said in the question, daily-periodic and deterministic.

Comment: This will be the last comment I make. As I have mentioned, you need to define the probability distribution you want. Statistical significance is related to probability, and you need to know what probability distribution you want to work with before you can assess any analytics. Describing the data does not satisfy this. As has already been mentioned by myself and other users, you are missing quite a lot that is needed to make this discussion more formal and rigid. Your understanding of what you're trying to ask seems tenuous, and I encourage you to exercise humility and rethink your question.

Comment: These are real data measures. they have no certain distribution as in any similar case. If you want to assume some probability distribution on the data, and work from there, it is a good practice that will help a lot. I did not assume any distribution on the data so that the answers will be more general. In any case, I do not think that it has anything to do with the answer to my question. My question can be answered without defining a specific distribution. In the case of equal groups, the correct answer would be that I have to use statistical significance, regardless of the distribution.